# How can I read a variables file into a bash script?

Tags: server, bash, scripts

I'm creating bash scripts to copy files search errors etc. from all our test servers.

I want to create an input file for these servers because they’re all test systems so they change hostname and IP from time to time.

Currently, I have to change all scripts if a server is changed.

I want one input file so I only have to change it there. 
So I only have to change the input file.

My input file I have created looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER1=$(echo "node1.example.com")
SERVER2=$(echo "node2.example.com")
etc.
```

I have tried

```
export file="path/to/input/file"
```

and also

```
read file="path/to/input/file"
```

but it doesn't work.

Now I want to read the values `$SERVER1`, `$SERVER2`, etc. into my other scripts.

How can I do that?

Comment: Note that the [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) combined with `echo` is redundant. You can write just `SERVER1=node1.example.com`.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this technique:

```
read VAR1 VAR2 < path/to/input/file.txt
echo $VAR1
echo $VAR2
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270289/bash-read-from-file-and-store-to-variables